# disk error, now can't log in to account

Tags: 14.04, login

My ubuntu was acting weird-- it wouldn't open libreoffice, and all my folders had padlocks on them. I wasn't sure what was going on, so I restarted. It said a disk error was detected, and I pressed f to fix it.

Now I'm unable to log in to my user account. I know I have the right password. When I press ctrl + alt + f1 to go to the shell, I can su to my account successfully. but when I try on the login screen, it flashes a black screen and brings me right back to the login screen.

Comment: Doesn't it complain about anything like "home folder not found"? You said all your folders had padlocks, did you change your home folder's permission? Try running `sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /home/yourusername` in tty1 and try logging in graphically again.

Comment: **Please stop using that hdd as soon as possible,** get a USB stick or DVD with Ubuntu on it, boot that and provide the output of: `smartctl --scan` and then `smartstl --all /dev/XdY` where `X` and `Y` is the output of the drives that came up with the first command!

Comment: I'm guessing you meant smartctl instead of smartstl for the second command. and only one directory came up when I ran the first one. I'll include all the output to make sure I'm doing this right:

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device`

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ smartctl --all /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: Permission denied`

I'm guessing this means my disk can't be read?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have experienced a hard disk crash.  It was not severe enough to prevent rebooting, but when it mounted the drive / partition, it found the error and mounted it read-only (a fallback for most mounts).  Thus the padlocks.

If you do not have a good backup, my advice would be to shut down the computer and carefully remove the hard drive.  You may be able to mount the drive on another machine (using a USB->SATA cable) and backup your important data.  I expect that the drive is no longer trustworthy.

Comment: I saw the padlocks before I even restarted my computer. does that still make sense with your theory?

Comment: Maria - yes, the remounting of the partition in read-only mode can happen while the computer is running if it finds problems.  @Fabby has good advice.